# No module named middleware on django deployment with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am using Django 1.5. My mod_wsgi file looks like this.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/genalytics')

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "genalytics.settings"


# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am seeing 500 Internal Server Error. The error in a log file:

```
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:35 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:35 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:35 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware fileupload.middleware: "No module named middleware"
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163] mod_wsgi (pid=26321): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/genalytics/genalytics/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Jun 18 16:06:36 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware fileupload.middleware: "No module named middleware"
```

Structure:

```
/opt/
   genalytics
     fileupload
     genalytics
     manage.py
```

Project name is genalytics. Application name is fileupload.

Full tree structure:

```
opt/

  genalytics/
    ├── fileupload
    │   ├── backend.py
    │   ├── backend.pyc
    │   ├── backends.py
    │   ├── backends.pyc
    │   ├── django.wsgi
    │   ├── encrypt.py
    │   ├── encrypt.pyc
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── forms.pyc
    │   ├── functions.py
    │   ├── functions.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── middleware.py
    │   ├── middleware.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── admin
    │   │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── ie.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   │   │   ├── img
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── chooser-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-arrowright.gif
    │   │   │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright_over.gif
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.min.js
    │   │   │       ├── admin
    │   │   │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── ordering.js
    │   │   │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │   │   │       ├── calendar.js
    │   │   │       ├── collapse.js
    │   │   │       └── urlify.js
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   ├── datepicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── datePicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui.css~
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline.css
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline_ie.css
    │   │   │   ├── screen.css
    │   │   │   └── screen.css~
    │   │   ├── endless_pagination
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── endless.js
    │   │   │       ├── endless_on_scroll.js
    │   │   │       └── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── transfer.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── upload.png
    │   │   │   └── up.png
    │   │   ├── js
    │   │   │   ├── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery
    │   │   │   │   ├── Copy of custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── date.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.4.1.min.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.bind.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.datePicker.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.dimensions.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.filestyle.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.pngFix.pack.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_3.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tooltip.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.usermode.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── ui.checkbox.js
    │   │   │   │   └── ui.core.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.9.1.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-latest.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.pajinate.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
    │   │   │   ├── test.js~
    │   │   │   └── transfer.js
    │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   ├── PIE.htc
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   └── style.css~
    │   ├── svn-commit.tmp
    │   ├── tasks.py
    │   ├── tasks.py~
    │   ├── tasks.pyc
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── ajax.html
    │   │   ├── base.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html~
    │   │   ├── deleted_files.html
    │   │   ├── edit_session.html
    │   │   ├── file_info.html
    │   │   ├── footer.html
    │   │   ├── forgot_password.html
    │   │   ├── form.html
    │   │   ├── header.html
    │   │   ├── list_files.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html~
    │   │   ├── login_backend.html
    │   │   ├── message_forgot.html
    │   │   ├── nav.html
    │   │   ├── new_password.html
    │   │   ├── notify.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html~
    │   │   ├── password_successful.html
    │   │   ├── reform.html
    │   │   ├── registration
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
    │   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
    │   │   ├── right.html
    │   │   ├── search_result.html
    │   │   ├── shared_by_me.html
    │   │   ├── shared_with_me.html
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   ├── synced.html
    │   │   ├── test.html
    │   │   ├── test.html~
    │   │   ├── thanks.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html~
    │   │   └── uploaded_notify.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── views.py~
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── genalytics
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.py~
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py~
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    └── manage.py
```

Comment: Does your fileupload module have a middleware.py file?

Comment: My application name is fileupload and yes it have middleware.py

Comment: In your wsgi script reverify that the paths do exist . Also make sure you have init.py file in fileupload directory

Comment: Yes verified. It works fine when I run the server in django development server but it's giving me error on Apache.

Comment: What is the base os dir you have specified?

Comment: what do you mean by base os dir?

Comment: What are the contents of the `fileupload` directory?

Comment: I have updated my question with the full tree structure.

Comment: Update the question with yoru Apache configuration for this site.

Comment: There's already a snippet of error from a log file in my question.

Answer (score 1):

How can you have genalytics appear twice in the /opt directory?

Anyway, you likely need:

```
sys.path.append('/opt')
```

as well else Python will not be able to find the fileupload package.

---

UPDATE

Now that you have fixed the directory structure in question, the next question is whether the directories are accessible and files are readable to user that Apache runs as?

In other words, Apache doesn't run as you, so directories/files must be readable by others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the tree structure I provided wasn't correct. Please see updated question.

Comment: Graham, the first is just a directory and I suspect the second is a module (this is default 1.5 django layout).

Comment: Yes, the directory and all the files as rwx for ugo.